# Removing duplicate-ish paths generated from recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql, duplication, array, recursive

I have some multi-parented data, that I run a recursive CTE against to find common ancestors:

```
item_id |item_name |path_name    |id_path_array |
--------|----------|-------------|--------------|
1       |D         |B->Two->D    |{9,4,1}       |
2       |E         |B->Two->E    |{9,4,2}       |
13      |W         |B->Two->D->W |{9,4,1,13}    |
14      |Y         |B->Two->D->Y |{9,4,1,14}    |
15      |X         |B->Two->E->X |{9,4,2,15}    |
16      |Z         |B->Two->E->Z |{9,4,2,16}    |
```

However, what I really want here is just the first two rows; I want to remove the rows that represent paths that have already been covered by a shorter path.  e.g. obviously if 'D' is a common ancestor then all of D's ancestors are too, so I don't want to include the paths for them.

I did think I had something with an array operator:

```
select * from common_ancestors q1
where exists (
    select 1 from common_ancestors q2
    where q1.id_path_array <@ q2.id_path_array and q1.item_id <> q2.item_id)
```

but even though it gives the right result here, I'm not convinced it's correct.  I would be happy to hear opinions or alternative solutions .

Desired result:

```
item_id | item_name | path_name | id_path_array
------: | :-------- | :-------- | :------------
      1 | D         | B->Two->D | {9,4,1}      
      2 | E         | B->Two->E | {9,4,2}
```

**db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kjBAERSmyTw6EnFw4fefih/2)**

Comment: Sorry, I'd updated the fiddle but not remembered to click 'Update'.  db-fiddle link should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `NOT EXISTS` and the `contains` operator reversed:

```
select 
    q1.* 
from 
    common_ancestors q1
where not exists
    ( select 1 
      from   common_ancestors q2
      where  q1.id_path_array @> q2.id_path_array 
        and  q1.item_id <> q2.item_id
    ) ;
```

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e67c7f38202b99fbcd314c1b4ac4958d)**